# Getting audio samples from speakers

Tags: ios, swift, fft, core-audio

So I have two questions:

1. Is there another (maybe low-level) way to get float* samples of the audio that is currently playing?
2. Is it possible to do it from inside a framework? I mean when you don't have access to the instance of AVPlayer(or AVAudioPlayerNode, AudioEngine, or even low-level CoreAudio classes, whatever) who owns the audio file? Is there a way to subscribe (in order to analyze, or also may be for modifying/equalizing) to audio samples that are being played via speakers/earphones?

I've tried to install a tap on `audioEngine.mainMixerNode` which works, but when I set the bufferSize more than 4096 (in order to compute high-density FFT), the callback is called less frequently than it should (about 3 times in a second instead of 30 times or even frequently).

```
mixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0,
                     bufferSize: 16384, //or 8192
                     format: mixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
{[weak self] (buffer, time) in
    //this block is being called LESS frequently...
}
```

I know that CoreAudio is very powerful and there should be something for this kind of purposes..

Comment: "Is there another (maybe low-level) way to get float* samples of the audio that is currently playing?" No. You can't access the audio output of other processes. You can only access audio streams that you directly control.

Comment: @RobNapier And what about getting sample more frequently with high density?

Comment: @RobNapier Is there any way to get samples with higher bufferSize more frequently than tap provides? F.e. using CoreAudio API?

Comment: The tap reads the input; it doesn't sample the output. By that I mean it should be based on the sources. I wouldn't expect it to combine everything and then resample at some high frequency. Put some known signals in and see if you're actually having a problem with the FFT. If you're getting 16k samples a 3Hz, that's over 44.1kHz. I wouldn't expect anything on an iPhone to sample audio faster than 44.1kHz.

Answer (score 0):

An iOS app can only get played audio samples from raw PCM samples that the app itself is playing.  Any visibility into samples output by other apps or processes is blocked by the iOS security sandbox.  An iOS app can sample audio from the device's microphone.

In an audio engine tap-on-bus, audio samples are delivered to the application's main thread, and thus limited in callback frequency and latency.  In order to get the most recent few milliseconds of microphone audio samples, an app needs to use the RemoteIO Audio Unit callback API, where audio samples can be delivered in a high-priority audio context thread.

Comment: The thing is I don't need a microphone samples at all. All I need is playback some audio file and get the samples realtime in order to compute high-density FFT and show some visualization..